# I can't get it to print out A02 instead of A2 because of int

Tags: c

```
int main(){

    char code;
    int coDe;
    printf("Enter code : ");
    scanf("%c%d", &code, &coDe);
    printf("%c%d", code,coDe);

}
```

Expected : `A02`
Actual : `A2`

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
printf("%c%02d", code, coDe);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing out.